# Command [generate-views] error: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 7.6.3

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, grails, view, controller

I have a Grails 6.0.0 project with scaffolding plunging in place. When I try to generate controller I get the following exception. create-controller is working fine.

```
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
Error |
Command [generate-views] error: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-bin.zip'. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I have also tried to generate the controller/view from Intellij Idea but ended up with the same error.

[image]
Any solution will be appreciated.

Thank you

Stacktrace is below

```
grails> generate-controller Book --stacktrace
<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [986ms]
> root project > Resolve dependencies of :console

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'generateController' not found in root project 'demo1'.

* Try:
> Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'generateController' not found in root project 'demo1'.
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskSelector.getSelection(DefaultTaskSelector.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.selection.DefaultBuildTaskSelector.resolveTaskName(DefaultBuildTaskSelector.java:97)
        at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildTaskScheduler.scheduleRequestedTasks(TaskNameResolvingBuildTaskScheduler.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildTaskScheduler.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultTasksBuildTaskScheduler.java:72)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$DefaultBuildProjectRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:205)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$DefaultBuildProjectRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:198)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:45)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(VintageBuildModelController.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$1(StateTransitionController.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$2(StateTransitionController.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:109)
        at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.scheduleRequestedTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController$DefaultWorkGraphBuilder.addRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:255)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$3(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:143)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:12
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExe
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
<-------------> 0% WAITING
> IDLE
cution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
| Error Command [generate-controller] error: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-bin.zip'. (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-bin.zip'.
```